# How to make linear regression for time intervals?

Tags: r

I have two to three hours data measured in seconds. I want to split this up in 11 intervals and make a linear regression on each interval.

The first time interval can be from 7-17 minutes and the next 18 - 27 minutes. My data has a column of seconds and and a column for the measuring in the champer.
I have started to make a plot

```
library(readr)
s24kul05p <- read.delim("C:/Data/24skulp05.txt", quote="")
View(s24kul05p)
s24kul05p
head(s24kul05p)
tail(s24kul05p)
data("s24kul05p")
plot(Ch1~Min, data=s24kul05p, ylim =c(170,250), xlim=c(1, 151), col="red")
abline(lm(Ch1~Min, data=s24kul05p))
```

After this I get a plot with one linear model, and it could be nice if it was possible make 11 linear models?

Answer (score 0):

Drop it into a matrix of 11 columns, then turn it into a data.frame again. You'll have 11 variables to run regression.

```
Y <- runif(231)
M <- matrix(Y, ncol = 11)
M <- as.data.frame(M)
```